# Jquery Modal showing up but blocking the site

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_modal_js&stacked=h). I want to do the same but using a link instead of a button. It shows the modal but the whole page turns dark and it gets blocked. I am not sure what am I doing wrong.

```js
$( "#openModal" ).click(function() {
 $("#myModal").modal();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="/assets/admin/js/myjavascript.js"></script>

   <a id="openModal">Open Modal</a> <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need the CSS bootstrap <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: When you look in the browser console due you see any errors or warnings?

Comment: @JonathanMarzullo Nope, nothing

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddle?

Comment: @Roy tried with and without it. Nothing.

Comment: @Roy is right, you just have to add  bootstrap css

Comment: Have you tried this `$('#myModal').modal('show')` in click event

Comment: Try the css without 's' of https. Like  h t t p://maxcdn....
And /assets/admin/js/myjavascript.js must be Absolute for Snippet.
Maybe add $(function() { /*your event*/ }); to the js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use bootstrap modal, you need:

For css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

For jquery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In the script:

```
$( "#openModal" ).click(function() {
 $("#myModal").modal();
});
```

It wouldn't work without reference:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Note: The version can be changed.